# XMLHttpRequest status always 0

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use the posts JSON from a wordpress.com website for part of a website, but my request's status always comes back as 0. Here is the function I am calling:

```
var wordPress;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/mywordpresssite.wordpress.com/posts/", true);

request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    wordPress = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    return wordPress;
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you `send()` it?

Answer (score 0):

In above code the link 
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/mywordpresssite.wordpress.com/posts/

the website {mywordpresssite.wordpress.com} is not registered..

Also, Please check this for more details:
https://en.wordpress.com/typo/?subdomain=mywordpresssite

Please try this snippet code for reference:-

```
//make request object   
var httpRequest;


//perform click event 
document.getElementById("ajax_json_Btn").addEventListener('click', makeRequest);

// make http request
function makeRequest() 
{
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (!httpRequest) {
alert('Giving up  Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
return false;
}
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
httpRequest.open('GET','https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/7', true);
httpRequest.send();
}

//handle the http response
function alertContents() 
{
if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) 
{
if (httpRequest.status >= 200 && httpRequest.status < 400) {
var myObj = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
alert(myObj.site_ID);
// alert(httpRequest.responseText);
} else {
alert('There was a problem with the request.');
}
}
}
}
```